# How to make an animation move relative to the parent element and not the body?

Tags: css, css-animations

I want to use [this](https://codepen.io/lautron/pen/JjXVPBm) css animation as a section in my home page.

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.flower-section{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: radial-gradient(#333, #000);
}

.set{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.set div{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}

.set div img{
    background-color: red;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.set div:nth-child(1){
    left: 5%;
    animation: animate 15s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -7s;
}
.set div:nth-child(2){
    left: 15%;
    animation: animate 20s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -5s;
}
.set div:nth-child(3){
    left: 25%;
    animation: animate 25s linear infinite;
}
.set div:nth-child(4){
    left: 35%;
    animation: animate 15s linear infinite;
}
.set div:nth-child(5){
    left: 50%;
    animation: animate 18s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -10s;
}
.set div:nth-child(6){
    left: 65%;
    animation: animate 12s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -8s;
}
.set div:nth-child(7){
    left: 75%;
    animation: animate 14s linear infinite;
}
.set div:nth-child(8){
    left: 85%;
    animation: animate 15s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -7s;
}
.set div:nth-child(9){
    left: 95%;
    animation: animate 19s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate{
    0%{
        top: -10%;
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(20px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    10%{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    20%{
        transform: translateX(-20px) rotate(45deg);
    }
    40%{
        transform: translateX(-20px) rotate(90deg);
    }
    60%{
        transform: translateX(20px) rotate(135deg);
    }
    80%{
        transform: translateX(-20px) rotate(180deg);
    }
    100%{
        top:110%;
        transform: translateX(-20px) rotate(225deg);
    }
}

.set2{
    transform: scale(1.5) rotateY(180deg);
    filter: blur(2px);
    z-index: 0;
}

.set3{
    transform: scale(0.8) rotateX(180deg);
    filter: blur(4px);
    z-index: 0;
}

.flower-title{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50% );
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 5em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

But when I try to implement it [this](https://codepen.io/lautron/pen/poyBzLP) happens.

The red squares seem to be moving relative to the whole body instead of the parent container. How can I fix that?
I've already tried making the parents and the children position relative, but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the red squares were just floating all over the place is that you had set your container element to `position: relative;` but then never set any of the squares to `position: absolute;`. By setting the squares to position absolute, everything you do on them will now be relative to their container.

What I did was set all the `.set div:nth-child(n)` to `position: absolute;`. I then went and gave `main` a background of white so that the red squares would have something to fall behind. I as well gave the `nav` a position of relative so that I could give it a higher z-index than the red squares, and so the squares start behind the nav instead of in-front.

I as well set the height of the container to a fixed height of 600px as apposed to 100% as the height in % is a relative unit, so the resulting height depends on the height of parent element's height.

Here is how I was able to achieve the outcome that you were looking for:

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

main {
  background: white;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
}

.flower-section{
    position: relative;
    height: 600px;
    background: radial-gradient(#333, #000);
    /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.set{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    /* z-index: 1; */
}

.set div{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
.set div img{
    background-color: red;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.set div:nth-child(1){
    position: absolute;
    left: 5%;
    animation: animate 15s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -7s;
}
.set div:nth-child(2){
    position: absolute;
    left: 15%;
    animation: animate 20s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -5s;
}
.set div:nth-child(3){
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
    animation: animate 25s linear infinite;
}
.set div:nth-child(4){
    position: absolute;
    left: 35%;
    animation: animate 15s linear infinite;
}
.set div:nth-child(5){
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    animation: animate 18s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -10s;
}
.set div:nth-child(6){
    position: absolute;
    left: 65%;
    animation: animate 12s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -8s;
}
.set div:nth-child(7){
    position: absolute;
    left: 75%;
    animation: animate 14s linear infinite;
}
.set div:nth-child(8){
    position: absolute;
    left: 85%;
    animation: animate 15s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -7s;
}
.set div:nth-child(9){
    position: absolute;
    left: 95%;
    animation: animate 19s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate{
    0%{
        top: -10%;
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(20px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    10%{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    20%{
        transform: translateX(-20px) rotate(45deg);
    }
    40%{
        transform: translateX(-20px) rotate(90deg);
    }
    60%{
        transform: translateX(20px) rotate(135deg);
    }
    80%{
        transform: translateX(-20px) rotate(180deg);
    }
    100%{
        top:110%;
        transform: translateX(-20px) rotate(225deg);
    }
}

.set2{
    position: absolute;
    transform: scale(1.5) rotateY(180deg);
    filter: blur(2px);
    /* z-index: 0; */
}

.set3{
    position: absolute;
    transform: scale(0.8) rotateX(180deg);
    filter: blur(4px);
    /* z-index: 0; */
}

.flower-title{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50% );
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 5em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    /* z-index: 1; */
}
```